# Why isn't my Nikon D7000 in Commander Mode working with my SB600 flash?

Tags: off-camera-flash, nikon-d7000, cls, sb-600, wireless-flash

I have a D200 and a D7000.  The D200 triggers the SB600 in Commander Mode without any issues.  The D7000 on the other hand will not trigger the SB600 with absolutely identical settings in Commander Mode to the D200's.  Am I missing some secret/hidden setting?  All channels/groups are identical.

Comment: The D7000 should be able to trigger the SB600.  Could you post the details of how you have the SB600 configured?

Comment: built-in flash set to CMD, built in set to -- value and then group A/B at 0, channel set to 1.   SB600 set to channel 1 group A and in remote mode.

Comment: commander mode is not working on my D7000 + SB-700 or SB-900 while I have no problem with D300 with same CMD settings. MY D7000 has the latest firmware 1.02 (2/5/2010)

Answer (score 6):

Some things to check:

- Make sure custom setting e3, **Flash cntrl for built-in flash** (**Menu** > **Custom Settings Menu** > **Bracketing/Flash** > **e3**) is set to **CMD↯**
- Under setting **e3**, Group A should be set to **TTL** or **M**. The SB-600 doesn't have a thyristor sensor, so **A** won't work.
- Make sure your compensation or power isn't set so low that you can't see much light.
- Under setting **e3**, set **Channel** to 1.
- The SB-600 should be in slave mode. Hold **Zoom** and **-** until the menu appears, and press **+** or **-** until the synchronization icon (squiggly right arrow) appears press **Mode** until this turns to **On**.
- Make sure your camera is in P, S, A, or M -- CLS doesn't work in Auto or Scene.
- Make sure you have line of sight from the D7000's on-camera flash to the IR sensor on the SB-600.
- Is the D7000's flash firing?

Oh, and one thing that I find really annoying that might be tripping you up: Make sure to hit OK after changing settings in the Commander Mode menu -- just changing them without hitting OK won't save them.

Comment: The answer is obvious: The camera is speaking German and the flash is speaking English, so of course it doesn't understand. The explanation in Krall's post got it to work for me - I'm sure it's buried in the user's manual somewhere, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: What exactly was it that got it to work, and did you have the same problem as chrisharry?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same setup working without any issues by following the instructions in the manual. But what is crucial, you have to **open up the integrated flash**.

My Settings:

[image: SB600 Settings]

[image: D7000 Settings]

Comment: Definitely, like I said everything is identical between the D200 and the D7000 including the integrated flash being popped up.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/pqcLw.jpg  I have no idea how to add images here, but there's my settings.

Comment: I am not sure about this, but maybe the camera and the flash are paired in some way. Maybe that - if any - pairing is not released?

Comment: there's a icon looking like a framed picture, right to an icon looking like binary code

Comment: I have tried with your settings, works for me :(

Comment: Calling Nikon today.  I still can not get it to fire with the D7K, all the while the D200 fires it again and again.   One thing I can note is that the preflashes don't seem to look or sound the same as the D200's.

Comment: Must be something wrong with the D7000.  I forced a 1.01 firmware re-load and still nothing.  The Nikon rep couldn't figure anything out either as her camera fired the sb600 perfectly with identical settings.  Guess I may have to downgrade for the remote flash shots Saturday at the wedding.

Comment: If it could be of any help : http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/ittlslave.htm

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a SB-600, so I borrowed an SB-700 and found the problem continued with that flash. I set them up to both run on the same channel and found they would fire / not fire at the same times, so I knew it had something to do with the camera. When I turned my built in flash from TTL to "--" everything started working fine. I don't know why, but the TTL flash of the built in flash was interfering in some way. I even found that I could leave it in TTL and cover the built in flash with my hand and the other flashed would then fire consistently. Weird, but glad I found a way to make it work.